# Who is C-3PO referring to?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In one of the final scenes of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, C-3PO is heard to exclaim "Thank the Maker!" My question is, who is the Maker? Is this in reference to some religious figure or deity, perhaps one he heard about on Tatooine? Or is he referring to Anakin Skywalker, his own "maker"? Any clarification here would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume it is simply the most logical droid version of "Thank god".  Whereas humans who believe in god think that god created them, droids would presumably be aware of the fact that they were created by machinery in a factory or a sentient being in a workshop, with no supernatural powers involved.  Thus, the person/machine who built the droid is effectively the droid's god.

Comment: i thought he was referring to Anakin his "maker"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maker), “The Maker” is basically a diety-like entity to droids; bold emphasis is mine:

> **The Maker**, also known **The One Who Creates**, was a being often referred to in deity-like terms by droids. **Droids claimed that the
>   Maker was the being that created the first droid. He changed them from
>   simple machines into intelligent creations.** Another belief was that
>   The Maker was actually the first droid.
>
> It seemed curious that new droids would possess knowledge of the
>   Maker, which led to two conclusions: **new droids were told by old
>   droids, creating a chain, or droid manufacturers included knowledge of
>   the Maker in droid programming to make them easier to control.**

That said, the concept of “The Maker” was not just limited to droids [as further explained on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maker):

> The Maker was also central to the religion of the [Sunesi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sunesi) people,
>   who also called him **the Giver**. They viewed him as the giver of
>   life and a master being "with a fine and glorious creativity and
>   affection," often adding a sense of humor to his qualities.
>
> [Mon Mothma](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mon_Mothma/Legends) believed in a Maker as well.